# Proof outline of limit of recursive sequence (using $\epsilon-N$ definition)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined as $x_1:=2, x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+x_n}$. It can be shown fairly easily that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ by first showing that $x_n$ is a bounded, monotonically decreasing sequence, then passing to the limit of $x_n$. However, I have to demonstrate this using the $\epsilon-N$ definition. [By using this thread as a reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948452/proving-the-limit-of-a-recursive-sequence), I have attempted a proof. Brief outline of my steps so far:

1. Show $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and monotone decreasing via induction. Hence, $\{x_n\}$ converges to a limit $L \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = L$.
3. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then for $n>N_0, N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\left| x_{n+1} - L \right| < \epsilon$.
4. Rewrite as $\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x_n}-L}{x_n-L}\right|\cdot\left|x_n-L\right|<\epsilon$.
5. Show that $\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x_n}-L}{x_n-L}\right| \leq 1 \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then this is where I'm stuck. I know I should claim that $L:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you may have some slight confusion about how the $\epsilon-N$ definition works. The way to think of it is that you have your sequence $\{x_n\}$ and a potential limit $L$. If you can show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$, then we can say for sure that $\lim x_n = L$. So step 1 affirms that the limit exists (this is good to do) and makes step 2 valid. Your next step is to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $|x_n - \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} | < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|x_{n+1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|=\left|\sqrt{1+x_n}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|=\frac{\left|1+x_n-\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{\sqrt{1+x_n}+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{\left|x_n-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{\sqrt{1+x_n}+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}\leq \frac{\left|x_n-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{1+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}\leq\frac{\left|x_n-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{2}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{2^2}\left|x_{n-1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|\leq...\leq\frac{1}{2^n}\left|x_1-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|\rightarrow0.$$
Now easy to use the $\varepsilon-N$ language.

Comment: Very clear and intuitive proof. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The missing part from your argument is $$ |x_{n+1}-L|=|\sqrt {1+x_n} -    \sqrt {1+L}|=\frac {|x_n-L|}{|\sqrt {1+x_n} +\sqrt    {1+L} |} $$ Note that$$ |\sqrt {1+x_n} +\sqrt    {1+L} |> 1+      \sqrt    {1+L}>2                         $$ Therefore $$|x_{n+1}-L|< \frac {|x_{n}-L|}{2}     $$The rest of the proof follows easily.

Comment: I'm confused... if $L=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, then $\sqrt{1+L}<2$. However, you have written the opposite. I do not think that step is valid.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed a 1. It is  fixed now.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.

Comment: Excellent. Have a good day